# File should have the date in de name from last month in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

My query result is saved on a unc path en the name of the file should be with last month date +name.
Then a email is send to my and en coworker.

The pain is naming the file with the date of last month.

```
DECLARE @Filename varchar(50), @year varchar(4), @month varchar(2), 
        @day varchar(2), @date varchar(10), @msg varchar(1000);

SELECT @Filename = 'WESA_New_DONOR_' + CONVERT(char(8), (@YEAR, getdate()), (@month, getdate()-1), 112) + '.csv';

EXEC [XXXX]..xp_cmdshell 'SQLCMD -S SQL00X -E -Q "SELECT * FROM [XXXX].[dbo].[VW_Logging] order by Tijdstip asc" -s";" -W -w 1024  -o \\XXXXXXX\dfs$\Algemeen\Loggings\XXXX\@filename'
```

Comment: `getdate() - 1` will get you the date of the previous day. Try `MONTH(getdate()) - 1` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not using `CONVERT` correctly.

From [Microsoft's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15):

> -- CONVERT Syntax:
>   CONVERT ( data_type [ ( length ) ] , expression [ , style ] )

Moreover, `getdate()` returns today's date. In order to get the year and month from it, you can use `YEAR()`and `MONTH()`. Therefore, if you want to get the the date of the previous  month, in this format `YYYYMM` for example, you can use the following snippet:

`SELECT CONVERT(char(6),CONCAT(YEAR(getdate()), RIGHT(CONCAT('00', MONTH(getdate()) - 1),2)),112)`

Comment: Thnx you for the solution.